# in python using a 'scrapy crawl craig' to run a spider error like this

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

/root/Python-2.7.11/craigslist_sample/craigslist_sample/spiders/test.py:1: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.spider` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

```
yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
```

ImportError: No module named _sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Python module `sqlite3` (using `pip`) and/or C/C++ library `sqlite3` (using installer normally used in your system - ie. `apt-get` in Debian)

---

Bisides you have to change `scrapy.spider` into `scrapy.spiders` (see `s` at the end) in file `test.py`

Comment: i used a pip install sqlite3 but it displays a error "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-spOHG2/sqlite3/
"

Comment: create new question with full error message. There can be more usefull information. Maybe you have to install C/C++ library first. Or maybe message asks for C/C++ headers *.h so you have to install `sqlite3-dev` (using system installer). Or you have to install it as root (using `sudo` command)

Comment: ya okay bro thank you i will create another question

Comment: or try to find answer on SO or Google using other information from message. Maybe someone already answer for this problem.

Comment: This is wrong, sqlite3 should not be downloaded using pip and indeed will give you a nice error to remind you of such **RuntimeError: Package 'sqlite3' must not be downloaded from pypi**. sqlite3 is part of the standard lib.